# Does the bus Monte Amiata Scalo → Montalcino stop at Castelnuovo dell'Abate?

Tags: public-transport, italy, tips-and-tricks, tuscany

I'm planning to stay some days at Siena. I would like to explore a little bit the area around this city using the public transportation system. I've noticed a bus from the [Tiemme SpA company](http://www.tiemmespa.it/index.php/Viaggia-con-noi/Orari-e-linee/Siena/Extraurbano)
going from Monte Amiata Scalo to Montalcino. I've also seen at Google Maps that there is a [bus stop at Castelnuovo dell'Abate](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Castelnuovo+Abate,+53024+Castelnuovo+dell'Abate+SI,+Italy/@42.9947346,11.5195339,20z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x132971e1308edd55:0x1820315cf37c0e2), quite near the  Sant'Antimo abbey. However, I'm not sure if the bus stops there because this stop doesn't appear at the timetable provided by the company website. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I went there, so I can now assure that the bus really stops there. I discovered that, in general, buses from [Tiemme SpA company](http://www.tiemmespa.it/index.php/Viaggia-con-noi/Orari-e-linee/Siena/Extraurbano) do have many more stops than the ones showed at the timetables that you can find at the company website. This bus stop is ideal to go from Montalcino to the Sant'Antimo abbey by walk, a very nice stroll, and then return to Montalcino by bus.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Google Maps the P1 line passes through that stop](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Monte+Amiata+Scalo,+Italia/Montalcino,+SI,+Italia/@42.994772,11.5197416,19.5z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x13296e0a996e6bf3:0xbb2f38984f7be81c!2m2!1d11.5458268!2d42.9765438!1m5!1m1!1s0x132970f197310557:0x4082c90e3e5a5d0!2m2!1d11.4889954!2d43.0551191!3e3?hl=it). You can see if you select the public transport option, it lists many more stops.

I regularly use Google Maps to take public transports in Italy so I'm pretty confident that it's correct, and in fact you can see a reference to [sienamobilità](http://www.sienamobilita.it/). In any case you should probably ask for confirmation to the driver when you take the bus.

Comment: I have noticed that, but, as I have said, what it seems strange to me is the fact that this bus stop doesn't appear at the timetable provided by the company website.

Comment: @Charo Yes but note that the name of the line is *Monte Amiata Scalo - **Castelnuovo Abate** - La Croce - Montalcino*.  I have sent an email to Tiemme to ask for confirmation, even though I'm quite sure is just an error on their part.  As I wrote in the answer in the Google Maps result you can see that the stops are provided by sienamobilità which is the company that handles public transports in Siena, so it's official.

Comment: Thank you for sending the email! I have also noticed that. My fear is that the bus stops could be different at summer period (timetable says it's valid from 11/06/16) from the rest of the year.

Comment: Haven't you received any answer to your email?

Comment: @Charo Unfortunately not. When submitting the request there is a note that says that requests for information will be handled when possible and if you need urgent information you should call them.